# python Tkinter - how to loop on data with a next button

Tags: python, tkinter

My goal is to read a JSON file create a GUI with labels containing the first data set. Now I want a next button which should update the GUI and update the labels with the second data set and so on.

So I expect to see (after start): 127#13:21:17#13:34:30
And after clicking next I expect: 168#13:16:50#13:30:35
and so on...

I'm new to python but so far the documentation of TKinter didn't helped me. Any guidance is appreciated.

**test.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import json

f = open('bus_arrival.json')
myJSON = json.load(f)

window = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=300, height=80)
canvas.pack()
window.title("Hello World")
    
def next_btn():  
    print("test")

button = tk.Button(text='Next', command=next_btn)
canvas.create_window(230, 20, window=button)

# the result is a Python dictionary:
for ad in myJSON["bus"]:
    text = tk.Label(window, text=ad["Bus Service"] + "#" + ad["1st Bus"] + "#" + ad["2nd Bus"])
    canvas.create_window(150, 20, window=text)

window.mainloop()
```

**bus_arrival.json**

```
{
    "bus": [
        {
            "Bus Service": "127",
            "1st Bus": "13:21:17",
            "2nd Bus": "13:34:30"
        },
        {
            "Bus Service": "168",
            "1st Bus": "13:16:50",
            "2nd Bus": "13:30:35"
        },
        {
            "Bus Service": "27",
            "1st Bus": "13:12:38",
            "2nd Bus": "13:21:00"
        },
        {
            "Bus Service": "72",
            "1st Bus": "13:13:24",
            "2nd Bus": "13:20:45"
        },
        {
            "Bus Service": "",
            "1st Bus": "",
            "2nd Bus": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when the last service information has been shown and the "Next" button is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create and hide canvas items by using `canvas.itemconfigure` and setting the state to "normal" or "hidden". If you store references to the canvas windows as you create them you can show and hide them in `next_btn`.

```
results = []
current_result = -1
current_window = None
    
def next_btn():
    global current_result
    # Hide the previous window
    canvas.itemconfigure(results[current_result], state = "hidden")
    # Increment the window counter
    current_result += 1
    # Loop back to the start if the end is reached
    if current_result == len(results):
        current_result = 0

    # Show the current window
    canvas.itemconfigure(results[current_result], state = "normal")
    

button = tk.Button(text='Next', command=next_btn)
canvas.create_window(230, 20, window=button)

# the result is a Python dictionary:
for ad in myJSON["bus"]:
    text = tk.Label(window, text=ad["Bus Service"] + "#" + ad["1st Bus"] + "#" + ad["2nd Bus"])
    results.append(canvas.create_window(150, 20, window=text, state="hidden"))
# Create the first window
next_btn()
```